# Angular Repeater and First attempt at using Angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller, dotnetnuke, repeater

I'm trying to use angular for the first time in an ASP.Net/DotNetNuke MVC Project.

View:

```
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.DnnWebViewPage<IEnumerable<IMT.AdvancedProductSearchMVC.Models.SearchTerm>>
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Helpers

<script src="/DesktopModules/RazorCart/Core/Content/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="APSApp" class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Terms" ng-model="searchTerms" />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="apsCtl">
        <table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in searchTerms">
                <td>{{r.DisplayText}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="r.SearchInput"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="DesktopModules/MVC/AdvancedProductSearchMVC/Scripts/AdvancedProductSearch.js"></script>
```

AdvancedProductSearch.js

```
 aps = angular.module('APSApp', []);
aps.controller('apsCtl',
    function(APSService, Features, $scope, $http) {
        alert("calling factory");
        $scope.searchTerms = [];
        APSService.getAPS(successFunction, failureFunction);

        successFunction = function(data) {
            alert("success");
            $scope.searchTerms = data;
        };

        failureFunction = function(data) {
            alert("failure");
        };
    });

aps.factory('APSService',
    function($http) {
        alert("getting factory");
        return {
            getAPS: function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
                //var APSService = {};
                $http.get('/Desktopmodules/MVC/AdvancedProductSearchMVC/AdvancedProductSearch/GetAPS').success(onSuccess).error(onFailure);
            }
        };
    });
```

Of course, it's not working. My controller never gets called, for instance and I don't know what I'm doing. 
How do I correct my code to make this work?

Comment: post the code for AdvancedProductSearch.js

Comment: I did. That's the javascript at the bottom with the angular commands.

Comment: angular commands?

Comment: Sorry. Angular statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of reading angular docs and examples and a lot of testing, it's now working:

My AdvancedProductSearch.js

```
var aps = angular.module("APSApp", []);
aps.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
        return data !== undefined ? $.param(data) : null;
    };
});

aps.factory('SearchTerms', 
    function($http) {
        return {
            getSearchTerms: function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
                const rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
                $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/AdvancedProductSearchMVC/AdvancedProductSearch/GetAPS",
                    headers: {
                        "ModuleId": moduleId,
                        "TabId": tabId,
                        "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
                    }
                }).success(onSuccess).error(onFailure);
            }
        };
    });

aps.controller('APSCtl',
    function(SearchTerms, $scope) {
            $scope.searchTerms = [];
            successFunction = function(data) {
                $scope.searchTerms = data;
                console.log($scope.searchTerms);
            };

            failureFunction = function(data) {
                console.log('Error' + data);
            };
            SearchTerms.getSearchTerms(successFunction, failureFunction);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AdancedProductSearch.js has a different module name and you are using a different module name in your HTML.

Rename the module name in your script and add a empty dependency as follows

```
  angular
        .module('APSApp',[])
        .controller('apsCtl', apsCtl)
    ;
```

Comment: I changed that. I'm now getting an error in the debugger:  SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'apsCtl' is not defined which, I assume, is coming from <div ng-controller="apsCtl">

Comment: I've updated the AdvancedProductSearch.js. I'm still trying to use the controller/factory model. It's still not working. Any advice?

Comment: It's funny. It looks like my controller or something is conflicting with another angular controller:    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/unpr?p0=FeaturesProvider%20%3C-%20Features%20%3C-%20apsCtl
   at Anonymous function (http://locallyheard.com.dnndev.kvalley.com/DesktopModules/Mandeeps/Libraries/Common/Frameworks/AngularJS/1.3.9/angular.min.js?cdv=308:38:301)

Mandeeps is a dotnetnuke skin.

Comment: Mandeeps is a dotnetnuke skin. what is this? :P